# Selenium test for interaction between two users

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests

I need to test user chat system with selenium. Currently I do that manually by opening two browsers, logging in each with different test user, and send messages between the two users.

My question is how I can automate that with selenium?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I never tried that, but I guess you can easily have two different instances of WebDriver:

```
 driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();
```

should IMHO run two different Firefox browsers where you can play around. But again, I never tried this approach, so I might be wrong

Comment: You can solve the overlap problem by either opening two different browsers (eg: firefox and chrome) or by using selenium grid and opening the browsers on different machines.

Comment: I tried and it seems to work fine. What would be the problem with the sessions overlapping ?

Comment: The problem with session overlapping could be, that if you log in as user in one driver and in other you would like to log in as admin. In that case the other window might already log you in as the same user...

Comment: I've tried to use 2 firefox drivers with my site with secure cookie login, and everything seems perfectly fine : each driver has its own cookies ...

Comment: Good for you. As stated in my answer, I did not try it. So thats why I was not that sure if my approach can help you. BTW... caring for accepting the answer if it works fine? :)

Answer (score 0):

Its hacky, but could you run two instances of Selenium then run two tests simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

Two drivers seems like a nice fit. If that's not possible, try using two different frameworks.

HeadlessUnit and Selenium, for example. Don't really know if they would be stepping on each other toes.