# Geb - How to use two users/browsers at the same time?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, geb

I'm writing automate tests using geb+selenium.
I have a lot of scenarios that requires dialog between users like:

1. Buyer create dialog
2. Seller response
3. Buyer response
4. Seller use some option
5. Buyer Use some option... etc

How to automate this test without logout/login before every step? 
I've tried to start 2 browsers but it's much harder to do than I thought.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you persevere and find a way to simplify working with multiple browser instances (unfortunately using multiple windows of the same WebDriver instance as suggested in other answers will not suffice as session will be shared across them). It's harder then it should be, I agree, but you are indeed trying to test behaviour of the system when used by two people concurrently using different browsers.

Historically [this github project](https://github.com/alxndrsn/geb-multibrowser) which is an attempted at simplifying working with multiple browsers in a single test has been circulated on Geb user mailing list and I'd suggest you have a look at it. Craig Atkinson has also written [a blog post](http://atkinsondev.com/blog/geb-multiple-browsers/) based on that project.

Given that this comes up over and over again, it's probably worth for Geb to come with some kind of support for this out of the box. Unfortunately I've not come up with a clean enough implementation of it I'd be happy with. Feel free to create an issue in Geb's tracker and start a discussion by sharing your experience.

Answer (score 0):

Write the login code in `@BeforeSuite`. This way, login will only be done once before all the test cases, then add logout in `@AfterSuite` to end the suite with logout.

Comment: This is not answer for my question. I can do this only if I have one user, but it's pointless in my case.

Comment: Ok. Now I get it. You are trying to open two browsers with different logins. One will be buyer and another will be Seller. And you want to automate the communication between the two.

Answer (score 0):

From the book of geb, it seems there are methods for working with multiple windows:

http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#working-with-multiple-tabs-and-windows

Seems there is a `withNewWindow()` method and even the ability to get all open windows. No experience of using this behaviour though.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 different users that will have different login details, which is why you have considered having 2 browsers running while this dialog happens between the 2 users.

I'm guessing you wrote tests that did something like:

```
login as buyer, open dialog
login as seller, respond
login as buyer, do stuff
login as seller, respond to stuff
etc...
```

If it was me, i'd look at stubbing the responses.  So 2 seperate tests, one for the Buyer where the Seller actions are stubbed, and one for the Seller where the Buyer actions are stubbed.

Using 2 browsers is possible though - see this question:  [Selenium test for interaction between two users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983998/selenium-test-for-interaction-between-two-users)

Answer (score 0):

You can open a new browser instance in Selenium with the command WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); (or FirefoxDriver or SafariDriver or ...).
This will open a new browser in a new window in a new session.